# Convert CDI (DiscJuggler) format to something else, like ISO

Tags: images, conversion, iso-image, burning, compact-disc

What tools can I use to convert a DiscJuggler image (I don't have that software) which uses the extension `cdi`, to a more standard format like `iso`?

Personally I am using a Macintosh with OS X 10.6 but I would think it to be appropriate to answer for Windows, Mac, and the Unices.

**Update**
Bonus for answering other formats like Nero (`nrg`), Alcohol (`mdr`), etc.
I already tried AnyToISO (a cross platform app) but it crashed on my `nrg` file, and it halved the size of the `cdi`, which considering that its a boot disc for a dreamcast, does not bode well.

Comment: Is that the newest buzzword... "Unicies"? Multiple Unix flavors?

Comment: Okay I misspelled it; it's fixed; Alternative forms are Unixes and Unixen; It refers to Linux flavors, BSD(s), and commercial ones like Solaris.

Comment: i've always preferred the term `*nix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CDIrip](https://github.com/jozip/cdirip) software, that has been compiled for Windows, OS X, *and* Linux. It will allow you to convert CDI images to ISO images.

[image]

Comment: Link is dead and there doesn't seem to be a mirror.

Comment: CDIrip is mirrored on Github: https://github.com/jozip/cdirip